# Custom 404 Rewrite + Exclude main dir from rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I use `.htaccess` to display my 404 page, while showing the requested URL in the browser instead of the actual 404 URL. To do so, I have this line in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php [L]
```

This works good whenever I go to a non-existent file (i.e. `blalba.php`).

The problem is: When I try to go to my main site *dir* (i.e. `http://example.com/`), I see the 404 page. When I directly go to my index file (i.e. `http://example.com/index.php`), everything works just fine.

How could I modify the `.htaccess` to **not** redirect my main *dir*?

So that, in fact, the main *dir* is excluded from the rewrite code above.

**ANSWER:**

See answer below and adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just forgot to tell apache that it needs to "default" to index.php if nothing is precised in the url. Here's how you do:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

---

Other answer about 404

I've had the same problem a few days ago. It's simple: assign the error document to 404.php. Whenever there's a 404, the server makes an internal redirection so that it can craft properly the web page.

So here's a sample of my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName x.fr
    ...
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    # activate rewrite engine:
    RewriteEngine On

    # *IMMEDIATELY* treat 404
    # if 404.php then stop immediately
    RewriteRule /404.php - [QSA,L]

    # From now on your can apply all your rules:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    # Sample of how I do a 404:
    RewriteCond %{ENV:PATH_LOCAL} notfound
    # "not found" 404 :
    RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

With all that you should be able to create your own rewriterules with proper 404 "filtering".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, i wasnt able to get it to work the way I want. `http://example.com/` still shows `404` - Since I am a newbie with htaccess, I could have made a mistake, but I wasnt able to "exlcude" the main dir from my rewrite rule.

Comment: LOL! I didn't read your question properly! I've added another answer

Comment: After trying your edited answer, it was still redirecting "/" to 404.php, however after trying some more and adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, it now works :)

Comment: It was **that** simple? Damn, sometimes I forget the most basic stuff to check before doing anything else...

Answer (score 1):

The following rule redirects to contact.html with subject= referencing the failed page

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /contact.php
    RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ /contact.html?subject=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L,R]
```

Comment: Note: In this example, the intermediate file, contact.php does not need to actually exist!